# Deploying a PyQt application on Windows Vista x64

Tags: python, 64-bit, pyqt

I'm working on an application for a client/friend using PyQt. I've been working on Linux and testing on Vista, but the target computer is Vista x64. Now, Python comes with compiled binaries of Python 2.6 for 64 bit Windows, but Riverbank don't provide 64 bit binaries for PyQt.

I don't have much access to the target computer, so I can't really go through the [hassle of compiling PyQt](http://eoyilmaz.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-compile-pyqt4-for-windows-x64.html). [This Google code project](http://code.google.com/p/pyqt4-win64-binaries/downloads/list) might be the solution, but I'm not sure if it's going to work.

Can I use something like py2exe from 32 bit Vista, or would I have to have to make the executable from a 64 bit machine with PyQt 64 bit installed? Basically, am I going to have to compile PyQt on the target machine?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to compile to the 32-bit (x86) and include 32-bit PyQt binaries and all will be well. 64-bit Windoze will run the project in a WOW64 process, and there shouldn't be compatibility issues.

Comment: I tried installing Python2.6 x86 and then PyQt x86, but the PyQt installer said it couldn't find Python2.6. I had assumed that it was to do with 64 bit, but maybe that was a separate issue...

Comment: Ah, yes... because WOW64 redirects the Registry entries and such that the installers use to locate the installed Python version.

If you set the environment variable PYTHONPATH to something like "C:\Python26\;C:\Python26\DLLs\;C:\Python26\Lib\;C:\Python26\Lib\lib-tk;" (adjusted to your version and paths, of course), the PyQt installer *should* reference that.

Answer (score 1):

From the same link you posted, the guy made a binary for Python 2.6

http://www.ozgurfx.com/downloads/PyQt-Py2.6-gpl-4.5.4-1_amd64.exe

Here's my source:
http://www.mail-archive.com/python_inside_maya@googlegroups.com/msg01977.html

Note: do not forget the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64), but I guess most computer already have it installed ... just a reminder.